# Do ISP know which DNS Provider I use?

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, isp, google-public-dns

I wanted to know can ISP know which DNS I use?

**1.For example if I use Google/OpenDNS do ISP knows that
I used third party dns?**

Also I have doubt about Google DNS and ISP

I use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as my dns servers replacing ISP dns

Lets I enter a website like website.com and it returned NXDOMAIN as website did not exist

Since website dont exist and no ip address connected to that only
thing dns query done and I used already google public dns

**2.Do ISP knows I tried to access that website which dont exist?**

Note:I did not use VPN or anything only used Google DNS before and tested no dns leak while using google dns or ISP dont hijack dns by redirecting as I checked by pinging non existent domain it dont return fake ips so my ISP dont hijack dns https://hackercodex.com/guide/how-to-stop-isp-dns-server-hijacking/

**Well I know law enforcement dont take action on such newbies the question was whether its possible but answer remains uncertain and no way to test even**

Answer (score 0):

1. If your ISP really really wanted to know, they could scan your packets for traffic to well-known DNS servers like 8.8.8.8.

   The question is why they wanted to pay money (and it costs money to do so, for every customer) to find out.

   So what's in for your ISP if it spies on you?

2. And they could equally well deep-inspect DNS traffic, and figure out if you ask for a non-existing domain. But again, what's in for the ISP if it does that? People make typos all the time.

But what you probably really want to ask is

3. Can I stop my ISP from DNS hijacking?

   Yes, you always can. The ISPs that do use quite simple methods normally, because again it doesn't pay for them to use more resilient ones. And even if they use more resilient ones, you can always work around whatever it is they do.

   But this hasn't anything to do with questions (1) or (2).

**Edit**

DNS lookup is not encrypted, so anyone on the transmission path (your home router bugged by law enforcement, your ISP, the internet backbone, government taps on the internet backbone, the company hosting the DNS server, e.g. Google) can log this.

Again, the question is why they should do this. If you are afraid that law enforcement will come after "your friend", the practical answer is "no, they won't, if he's just an ordinary guy".

If "your friend" has used the Darknet in the past, and the cops are already on to "your friend", because he made millions on the darknet and is therefore interesting to law enforcement, then yes, they could have logged this.

Comment: Actually its my friend who clicked a dark web site .onion by mistake and this case he asks since onion sites dont connect with normal browser do they have logged/record he tried to access that onion website?He used Google DNS and dark web very illegal in his country  and I think Google DNS protected him somehow since the ISP DNS was not used for looking .onion site nor site was connected also.What you think?

Comment: "So what's in it for your ISP if it spies on you?"... The same thing that's in it for every corporation, MONEY! (information = revenue opportunity)

Comment: Question is whether ISP can log non existent domains or  like .onion sites if by mistake clicked cant be connected and shows same error as non existing domain NX Domain error when we use Google DNS

Comment: Yes, ISPs can do this. This is distinct from saying that they do. - its unlikely beneficial for them - as if they wanted to take advantage they could just intercept the requests.  Certainly Google (if you used 8.8.8.8) would know, although they likely wouldn't care - and depending on your country maybe its likely a super secret spy agency knows but will never admit to knowing.

Comment: I wont care whether google knows main thing so ISP can know if then how they can log dns made by 3rd party DNS to non existent domains I am really amazed

Comment: As I wrote: Everyone on the route can. I also wouldn't be surprised if Google regularly cooperates with law enforcement. What makes you think you (sorry, "your friend") cannot trust your ISP, but you can trust Google?

Comment: Yes Google is trusted than ISP much cases

Comment: Please read [Google's policy](https://support.google.com/transparencyreport/answer/9713961?hl=en), note the absence of information about DNS ... Also note they **do** comply with government requests for information.

Comment: So this answer is uncertain and depending on ISP friends case I know I am not such a noob law enforcement have big boys to track but the question answer depends on many things